# std::cout to print character N times

Tags: c++, cout

How can I print a character N number of times using `std::cout` without looping?

Is there a way to move the text cursor back to nullify the effect of `std::cout << std::endl;`? i.e. to move up a line (say we never printed anything after doing the `std::cout << std::endl;` operation).

Comment: C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678948/how-to-repeat-a-char-using-printf

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
 std::cout << std::string(100, '*') << std::endl;
```

To move a line up, you have to resort to terminal escapes (assuming that `isatty()` indicates that you are running on one).

Comment: Or not pint the EOL in the first place ??

Comment: True, I considered that. In my particular program it seemed easier otherwise.

Comment: This does not work with Unicode characters.

Comment: @Mr.Clear Clearly, unicode wasn't supported (and the little machinery that exists has been deprecated). The best idea I have would probably be `fmt::format` here : https://compiler-explorer.com/z/1f98dTn5e

Answer (score 28):

```
std::cout << std::setfill(the_char) << std::setw(100) << "";
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to back our way to nullify the effect of cout << endl;
>   i.e. to move up a line(say we never printed anything after doing the
>   cout << endl; operation) Thank you so much!

Use the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) (or an if statement if you refer) ... something like ...

```
void PrintCharNtimes(char chatToPrint; int numTimes)
{
   std::cout << std::string(numTimes, chatToPrint) << (numTimes > 0) ? std::endl : ;
}
```