# How to print variable multiple times with one printf statement in C

Tags: c, printf

After searching stack overflow and going through several tutorials I still can't find out how to print a variable multiple time with one printf statement.

This is what I want to get as a result:

1111111111

2222222222

3333333333

by using something like this:

```
for(int i=1; i<4; i++)

{
    printf("%d", i);   //it would be great to add something here
}
```

But without another for loop!

Or it can be easily asked like this, I want printf to print variable int i=1; multiple times in a row without loops. So output would be 1111111111

Comment: `printf( "%d%d%d%d\n", i, i, i, i )` springs to mind. Any way to be more specific?

Comment: For printing a dynamic amount of numbers, what is wrong with a second loop?

Comment: Already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678948/how-to-repeat-a-char-using-printf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is...it is not possible to do what I wanted on the way I wanted. The best way is to use another for loop inside existing one.

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a second loop, like this :

```
int i, j, number = 1;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        printf("%d", number);
    }
    printf("\n");
    number++;
}
```

where `4` is the number of different numbers you want to print and `3` is the  number of times you want to print a number. In your case, this will print :

> 111
>
> 222
>
> 333
>
> 444

Otherwise, you have to specify manually the number of arguments in `printf` :

```
int i = 1;
printf("%d%d%d\n", i, i, i);
```

Answer (score -1):

it is impossible to print it without loops(for, while, do while). you can also use goto statement but it is not recommended.

```
        int counter = 1;
label1: printf("1");
        counter ++;
        if (counter <= 10)
           goto label1;
```

as I said, using goto is bad. so i recommend loops.