# How to print a char repeatedly using format specifier instead of loop?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I want to print a char `'*'` repeatedly where I give the no. of times the asterisk should be repeated.

**Example:** `count = 20` and I want to print `********************` using `printf()` and **format specifiers.**

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678948/how-to-repeat-a-char-using-printf) answer your question?

Comment: I want the code for count =n not for small constant like 20. I mentioned that as an example.

Answer (score 2):

There is certainly no way to achieve that using only format specifier. You could hide your loop in a macro maybe but you'll definitely need a loop somewhere.

Comment: The duplicate reference proves otherwise.

Comment: From my understanding, it doesn't. The duplicate accepted answer shows `%0*d` and then replaces `0` with `*` (in a loop), but OP asked specifically `instead of loop`.

Comment: @KamilCuk look at the second answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with standard format specifiers provided by `printf()`. However, there's a hacky solution (assuming the maximum padding length is reasonable), if you are willing to waste some space to store a filler string in your program.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *fill = "********************"; // 20 chars

    printf("%.*s\n", 10, fill);
    printf("%.*s\n", 15, fill);

    int n = 20;
    printf("%.*s\n", n, fill);

    return 0;
}
```

This works using `.*` to provide the maximum length of the string to print as first parameter.

Output:

```
**********
***************
********************
```

**NOTE**: you will only get up to `strlen(fill)` characters of padding (20 in the above example), anything more and `printf` will stop at the `\0` terminator of `fill`.

Comment: This answers the question but I am pretty sure this shouldn't be used in most cases.

Comment: @Puck it's definitely not idiomatic, but there are times in which you need a quick and dirty solution even in C. I think this is the closest it gets to what OP wants.

Comment: @Marco Boneli that answers my question up to a certain extent. Besides that could you mind providing me the solution for **count equal to some unknown value 'n'** instead of a known constant like 20? I want to overcome the issue of time complexity by avoiding loop.

Comment: @anonymous you can just use the variable instead of a number: `printf("%.*s\n", n, fill)`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("%.*s", 20, "********************************");;
  return 0;
}
```