# C++ equivalent of Python '#'*number?

Tags: python, c++, c++14

Is there an equivalent one-liner to `'#'*number`, which if number was 4 the output of that expression would be `"####"`, in C++? If there isn't an equivalent one-liner, I would like to know if there are any quick ways to do this that don't include a `for` loop.

Note: I am using C++ 14, on the program I'm working with I can't use C++1z (17), so no C++1z suggestions.

Comment: No. Use a for loop, where the iteration count is one less than the number you want, assuming your iteration count starts at 0

Comment: @NickMeyer Are you sure there aren't any other ways?

Comment: There might be some library that could handle that, but as far as I am aware, there is not.

Comment: Are you using a string? There is a fill constructor `string(size_t n, char c)`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897163/stdcout-to-print-character-n-times and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166630/how-to-repeat-a-string-a-variable-number-of-times-in-c

Comment: Yes, I am using a string, thank you @twain249. If you could post an answer with an example I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I stated in the comments there is a fill constructor in the `std::string` in c++.

```
string(size_t n, char c);
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/.

Answer (score 5):

As [std::string constructor provides an option](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string). Can be done simple as:

```
std::string(4, '#');
```

[Sample program](https://ideone.com/a3QRdN):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << string(4, '#') << endl;
}
```